# Exception : adding a window to a container. How to solve it?

Tags: java, swing, exception, jdialog, illegalargumentexception

I have a `JDialog` class named `Preferences`. This class creates a constructor like:

```
class Preferences extends javax.swing.JDialog {
          Preferences(java.awt.Frame parent,modal)  {
                      super(parent,modal);
                      //......
          }
}
```

In my program I want this preferences dialog to open up as I click a button from a `JFrame` form. After I registered the action listener on the button, I wrote the code inside as:

```
Frame fr = new Frame();
Preferences p = new Preferences(fr,false);
fr.add(p);
fr.setVisible(true);
```

When I run this code I get the following exception (as I click the button):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
```

What does this mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: You can't add one [top-level container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) to another, and you shouldn't mix AWT & Swing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What does this mean..

One top level container (dialog) cannot be added to another (frame).

> ..and how can i solve this ?

Just call `setVisible(true)` on the `Preferences` dialog, rather than adding it.

Answer (score 6):

You don't add the JDialog to the JFrame, that makes no sense whatsoever since the `add(...)` method is for adding components to be displayed ***in*** the container, not ***by*** the container. You display the JDialog from the JFrame's JButton's ActionListener. You also shouldn't be mixing AWT (Frame) components and Swing components together for no good reason.

Your question suggests that you would benefit greatly by going through the Swing tutorials.

Comment: He was actually trying to add it to a Frame rather than a JFrame. Not that it makes much difference to your point.

Answer (score 4):

JDialog and JFrame are [top-level container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html). I suggest that you should have to use `JFrame`, `JInternalFrame` and `JDesktopPane`.